# app crash on changing uilabel background color

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSTimer` that calls the `checkStatus` function every 2 seconds:

```
-(void) checkStatus
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        self.lblconnectionStatus.backgroundColor=RGB(0,153,0);
    }
}
```

The app crashes on: `self.lblconnectionStatus.backgroundColor=RGB(0,153,0);`

Here is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02244466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01af5a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x020fb5a1 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 881
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x020fb201 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 65
    4   UIKit                               0x00ad559c PushNextClassForSettingIMP + 383
    5   UIKit                               0x00acce56 TaggingAppearanceObjectSetterIMP + 50
    6   GIG-iPad                            0x0017ddcb -[TradeController checkStatus] + 763
    7   Foundation                          0x016f6607 -[NSThread main] + 76
    8   Foundation                          0x016f6560 __NSThread__main__ + 1326
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x02e20ecf _pthread_body + 138
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x02e20e45 _pthread_body + 0
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x02e1ef0e thread_start + 34
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: the shown code has nothing to do with the error. You are somewhere trying to insert a nil object into an array, which is not allowed. And what is the purpose of the autoreleasepool? What is RGB(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe "checkStatus" function have like,

```
[xxxx addObject:yyy];
```

Problem is yyy is nil so, Try this.

```
if (yyy != nil) {
　　[xxxx addObject:yyy];
}
```